# how to have delimeter/separate between <f:selectItems> for <p:selectManyMenu>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to have a separator/delimiter between `<f:selectItems>` for `<p:selectManyMenu>` this is JSF2 + Primeface3 web application. Please find the code below:

```
<p:selectManyMenu
  id="venue" value="#{PstOfrBen.selectedVenues}"
  required="true" style="width: 285px;height: 200px">
    <f:selectItems value="#{BsnsDshbrdBen.business.venues}" var="venue"
      itemLabel="#{venue.venueAsDisplayString}" itemValue="#{venue.seoURL}" />
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adapt the class of the menuitems:

```
.ui-selectlistbox-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: <f:selectItems> does not support 'class' property tried adding this css class to <p:selectManyMenu> but it doesnt work. Can you give me a code snipet?

Comment: Just add this class definition to your css-file. The items of the selectManyMenu will be rendered with this class.